null value for CustomEvent in Blazor wrapper for native JS Web Component
We are attempting to build a Blazor wrapper for our native Javascript web component library.
Our input emits a custom event valueChange whenever the user changes the value of the text field (i.e.: types/deletes stuff in it). We want to capture this event and retrieve the detail property in the CustomEvent, which contains the current text box's text:

library-input.js:
#updateValue(value) {
    // ... updating the native `value` attribute

    const valueEvent = new CustomEvent("valueChange", {
        detail: this.#value,
        bubbles: true,
    });

    this.dispatchEvent(valueEvent);
}

libraryInput.razor:
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@namespace BlazorWrapperForLibrary
@using System.Text.Json

<lib-input @ref="libInput" @onvalueChange="ValueChanged">
</lib-input>

@code {
    private ElementReference libInput;
    private const string JAVASCRIPT_FILE = "/js/library-components.js";
    private const string INTEROP_FILE = "/js/lib-input.interop.js";

    private IJSObjectReference? Module { get; set; }
    private IJSObjectReference? Interop { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    public string? Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<InputValueChangeEventArgs> ValueChanged {get; set;}

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            Module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", JAVASCRIPT_FILE);
            Interop = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", INTEROP_FILE);
        }
    }
}

CustomEvents.cs:
public class InputValueChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string? detail { get; set; }
}

[EventHandler("onvalueChange", typeof(InputValueChangeEventArgs), enableStopPropagation: true, enablePreventDefault: true)]
public static class EventHandlers
{
}

Counter.razor:
@page "/counter"
    <LibInput Value="newValue" ValueChanged="@((InputValueChangeEventArgs value) => InputChanged(value))">
    </LibInput>
@code {
    private string newValue = "undefined";

    private void InputChanged(InputValueChangeEventArgs value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value.detail);
    }
}


When I add an event listener for the valueChange on the document I can see the detail property is filled successfully.
When I put a breakpoint in the JS for Blazor in the devtools (onGlobalEvent(e) in the blazor.server.js) I can also see the detail property filled in.
When I inspect the Web Socket Messages I see ......BeginInvokeDotNetFromJS..1..DispatchEventAsync..I[{"eventHandlerId":7,"eventName":"valueChange","eventFieldInfo":null},{}]. I'm not sure if eventFieldInfo: null has anything to do with this.
When I put a breakpoint in the InputChanged() method in the Counter.razor file, the detail property is null.


What is Microsoft.SWCComponents.SBCInput ?  I tried to reproduce your issue, but there no element about swc-input. So do you mind create a brand new sample project which could reproduce the issue for us. Then we can investigate it easily.

@JasonPan The namespace was copy+pasted and not changed when anonymizing the code snippets. I updated the code in the question. To do a reproducible example would take a while, so first I'd like to know if the general approach to capturing CustomEvents from a native JS web component in Blazor is correct. If we're seemingly doing everything OK, then I could strip down everything and try to do a repo.

Hi Nelladel, I have tried again, still can't reproduce the issue.

Hi @JasonPan . Is there any chance you could upload a github repo with your repro? From what I understand from your comments, it looks as though it might be something related to our library, and not some issue between Blazor and Web Components. Thanks a million!

Hi Nelladel, I can't use github, sorry for that.

This may be related to your "InputValueChangeEventArgs" has "detail" being lowercase and Blazor expecting uppercase when it´s serializing to JSON

Thanks for that, but we tried both with Detail and detail because of that, and still the value came out as null.
